# How to get Formated date?

Tags: java, mysql, date, javabeans

I Have a bean , in that I have one property of date type.

```
private Date insurance_date;
public Date getInsurance_date() {
    return insurance_date;
}
public void setInsurance_date(Date insurance_date) {
    this.insurance_date = insurance_date;
}
```

But get method gives us a date with time so I wrote a formated method as,

```
public String getFormatedDoI() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String stirngDate = null ;

        if(insurance_date != null)
            stirngDate = df.format((insurance_date));               
        return stirngDate;
    }
```

But the problem is I have date in db as `2014-05-21` , when I use `getFormatedDoI()` method it prints `21-00-2014`. In fact for all the dates in place of month it displays `0`. How can I get exact formated date.? and the database I am using is `mysql`. The date coming from MYSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "dd-MM-yyyy" instead of "dd-mm-yyyy". The pattern "mm" stands for minutes not for month.

Answer (score 2):

Small mm is for minutes, capital MM is for month number, if you want to get month name you can use MMM, in your case use "dd-MM-yyy" instead of 'dd-mm-yyyy'.

```
public String getFormatedDoI() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String stirngDate = null ;

        if(insurance_date != null)
            stirngDate = df.format((insurance_date));

        return stirngDate;
    }
```

Should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

`mm takes minute`.

If you want month then use `MM`.

so instead of `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");`

use : `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");`

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) documentation on date format.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

instead of

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

It should resolve